# Get last several values from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm listing articles from `Article` model.

To get all of them I naturally use

```
var articles = db.Articles;
```

To get only last one:

```
var lastArticle = db.Articles.Last();
```

But now should I get, let's say, last four?

Article model:

```
ID
Name
DateCreated
Image
Content
```

Comment: According to what ordering criterion?

Comment: According to either `DateCreated` or `ID`, I don't think it matters which of those two.

Comment: Calling `Last` makes no sense anyway because tables do not have any order. You could get any article at all.

Comment: Yes I realize that, was just making a point rather than coding it correctly, so it would be clearer to what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks for the heads up anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order in reverse and get the first N elements:

```
db.Articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.DateCreated).Take(4)
```

If you want the result in ascending order, you can append `.OrderBy(a => a.DateCreated)`.

Comment: I knew it was something simple missing -_-... Completely forgot about `.Take()` Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var takeLast = db.Articles.OrderByDescending(d => d.ID).Take(4);
```

it will all depend on what you will be ordering

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
db.Articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.DateCreated).Take(4).ToList()
```

Also if you would like to create pagination then use:

```
db.Articles.OrderBy(a => a.DateCreated).Skip(20).Take(4).ToList()
```